# Using ListCellRenderers on selected entries

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist, listcellrenderer

I'm using a ListCellRenderer to edit the appearance of entries in a JList. Once they are selected (by clicking them, this code is within a click event) I call the ListCellRenderer to change the color of the text. If they are selected again I want the text to return to the normal color. The problem I am having is that once I select a second entry the first entry goes back to its normal color. How can I keep selected entries the selected color until they are actually deselected? Here is the section where I actually call the function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < selectedEntries.size() - 1; i++){
    System.out.println("Inside the for loop at entry:" + i);
    if(selectedEntries.get(i).equals(selectedEntry)){
        selectedEntries.remove(i);
        removed = true;
        renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(logEntries, value, index, false, false);
        System.out.println("Duplicate Entry Removed From List");
    }
}

if(!removed){
    selectedEntries.add(selectedEntry);
    renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(logEntries, value, index, true, false);
}
```

Just for ease of interpretation selectedEntries is an ArrayList containing each selected entry's text.

Comment: *"Once they are selected (by clicking them, this code is within a click event) I call the ListCellRenderer to change the color of the text"* No, that's not how it should work, the `ListCellRenderer` will be called again (by the `JList`) and the `isSelected` parameter will be `true`, to which you would render the values differently

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do you that, could you explain a little more? I've done my best to research ListCellRenderers but I'm still not very clear on a lot of stuff.

Comment: See my answer, [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once they are selected (by clicking them, this code is within a click event) I call the ListCellRenderer to change the color of the text

No, that's not how it should work, the `ListCellRenderer` will be called again (by the `JList`) and the `isSelected` parameter will be `true`, to which you would render the values differently

The `ListCellRenderer` is responsible for rendering the entire state, selected or not selected.

Have a look at [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details

For example

[image: List of stuff]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            model.addElement("Apples");
            model.addElement("Bananas");
            model.addElement("Peachs");
            model.addElement("Pears");
            JList<String> listOfStrings = new JList<>(model);
            listOfStrings.setCellRenderer(new FancyPancyListCellRenderer());
            add(new JScrollPane(listOfStrings));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static class FancyPancyListCellRenderer  extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        protected static final Font SELECTED_FONT = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12);

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                setFont(SELECTED_FONT);
            } else {
                setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
            }
            return this;

        }

    }

}
```

Also, `MouseListener` really isn't a suitable means by which to detect changes in the selection, what happens if the user selects rows using the keyboard?  You should be using a `ListSelectionListener` instead (but not to correct this issue).

Have a look at [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: I don't really want them to be able to select rows using the keyboard. My intention is for things to only be selectable by using the mouse, mouse+ctr or mouse+shift.

Comment: Oh wow, I get it now, so regardless of whether or not I call the ListCellRenderer if I select something the JList realizes it and updates the the entry panels layout. That awesome, thank you!

Comment: *"I don't really want them to be able to select rows using the keyboard"* - What you want and what the user will do are seldom the same thing ;)